# Run a Python EXE (created in PyInstaller) in C# Console Application

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, process, pyinstaller

I have an exe file created from `.py` file by using `PyInstaller` and it works while I'm opening manually. I want to open it by using C# in Console Application.

But my python exe file is not opening. Nothing is happening. I thought I could do like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start("C:/something.exe");
    }
}
```

That is perfectly working for exe files which are created in C#, but not for files which are created in Python with PyInstaller.

How can I open my file?

Comment: that should be `C:\something.exe` backslash and not forward slash, try it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions. First, shouldn't it be

```
"C:\\something.exe"?
```

As I understand C# requires two slashes, and two backslashes at that, or you put

```
r="C:\something.exe"
```

to make it a path.

Second, depending on whether this is for personal or commercial use you could just use the actual .py file and within the C# script write to the console to run the py file. I use this method in python sometimes, in python it's

```
os.system("py something.py")
```

and I believe there's a thing for this in c# called ironpython, which can be used like so:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"test.py");
}
```

Third, couldn't you just 'translate' it to C# instead of running the .exe?

Comment: but I don't want to run py file. I want to run exe file which is created by pyinstaller